# Is there any way to deploy volttron with code protection?

Tags: python, python-2.7, volttron

Is there a way to deploy Volttron or Volttron agents without exposing the source code of agents?

Answer (score 0):

While there is no  way included in the platform to do this there are tools that make it possible.

The first thing is that even if you only deployed python byte code the original source is easy to derive from this byte code. This is a waste of time.

I would try compiling your Agent code into C with Cython and then compile that into a pyc module(s) before deployment. Ultimately the module is run directly with the python interpreter so this should just work.